# Coloring text using regular expressions in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert the following text using regular expression such that text inside `^text^` is replaced by the text inside some HTML tags. (inside `<font color='red'>`and `</font>`

Example:

```
Input Text: Please select ^Continue^ to proceed with your call or ^Exit^ to call

Output Text: Please select <font color='red'>Continue</font> to proceed with your call or <font color='red'>Exit</font> to call
```

Is it possible to achieve above using regular expressions in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried? Is this text in the DOM somewhere or a string that you will later append to the DOM?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use   `yourstring.replace(/\^([^\^]*)\^/g,"<font color='red'>$1</font>")`

```
Explanation  -- Starting ^
               ------- Match everything but ^, in $1
                       -- End with ^
```

`g`is the global flag, meaning that the Regex will match all matches.

**example:**

```
text= "Please select ^Continue^ to proceed with your call or ^Exit^ to call"
result=text.replace(/\^([^\^]*)\^/g,"<font color='red'>$1</font>")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
your_string.replace(/\^(.*?)\^/g, "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
```

Example:

```
> a = "Please select ^Continue^ to proceed with your call or ^Exit^ to call"
"Please select ^Continue^ to proceed with your call or ^Exit^ to call"
> a.replace(/\^(.*?)\^/g, "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
"Please select <font color='red'>Continue</font> to proceed with your call or 
<font color='red'>Exit</font> to call"
```

Comment: You could also use a negated class `[^^]` instead of a lazy star ))))

Comment: I used this lazy star here only because of your recent comment :D
Trying to be unpredictable :)

Comment: yeah, you have a way to confuse my hair splitting engine.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly better to make some kind of parsing function, depends on your case, something like this.

Javascript

```
function wrapMarked(string, open, close) {
    if (typeof string !== "string", typeof open !== "string", typeof close !== "string") {
        throw new TypeError("Arguments must be strings.");
    }

    if ((string.match(/\^/g) || []).length % 2 !== 0) {
        throw new Error("We have unmatched '^'s.");
    }

    string = string.replace(/\^{2}/g, "");
    var index = string.indexOf("^"),
        result = "",
        state = true;

    while (index !== -1) {
        result += string.substring(0, index);
        if (state) {
            result += open;
        } else {
            result += close;
        }

        string = string.substring(index + 1);
        index = string.indexOf("^");
        state = !state;
    }

    return result + string;
}

var text = "Please select ^Continue^ to proceed with your call or ^Exit^ to call";

console.log(wrapMarked(text, "<font color='red'>", "</font>"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aVPxm/)